# Android app calculation error and crash

Tags: java, android, crash

So guys, here I'm trying to get the **inputs(day, month, year)** by getting the strings from the **edittext's** then convert then to int and make an addition then display it. 
 I think the code is wrong though because when I try to run this the app crashes, and if I remove those 3 lines that I marked by "//error" it doesn't crash but still the function won't work. 
 Can you help me here??

```
package com.example.bibiwars.skills;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Age extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_age);

    Button getage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getage);
    EditText ddtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dd);
    String dds = ddtext.getText().toString();
    final int dd = Integer.parseInt(dds);                          //error
    EditText mmtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mm);
    String mms = mmtext.getText().toString();
    final int mm = Integer.parseInt(mms);                           //error
    EditText yyyytext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yyyy);
    String yyyys = yyyytext.getText().toString();
    final int yyyy = Integer.parseInt(yyyys);                     //error
    final TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    getage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            output.setText("you wrote:" + (dd + mm + yyyy));
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Could you post the Logcat error message so we can see what type of error you are encountering? Is it a NullPointerException?

Comment: Can you provide what exceptions you are getting? Either `NumberFormatException` or anything else. As my doubt is you are getting empty string conversion on integer, as you have to get input string in button's click from edittext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Age extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_age);

    Button getage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getage);
    EditText ddtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dd);

    EditText mmtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mm);

    EditText yyyytext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yyyy);

    final TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    getage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             String dds = ddtext.getText().toString();
             int dd = Integer.parseInt(dds);

             String mms = mmtext.getText().toString();

             int mm = Integer.parseInt(mms);  

             String yyyys = yyyytext.getText().toString();
             int yyyy = Integer.parseInt(yyyys); 
            output.setText("you wrote:" + (dd + mm + yyyy));
        }
    });
}}
```

also before converting `String` to `Int`  check for null

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(yyyys))
{
    int yyyy = Integer.parseInt(yyyys); 
}
```

**Edit**

At `onCreate()` method, there isn't data filled, so it is always throwing `NullPointerException` or `NumberFormatException` - as said in comment by ***@ Roberto Tellez Ibarra***

Comment: I think this is the correct solution. At onCreate method, there isn't data filled, so it is always throwing NullPointerException or NumberFormatException

Comment: I am not the author my friend. I voted up your answer :D

Comment: yeah that fixed the error but how can I calculate the value of (dd + mm + yyyy) ?

Comment: Sorry @RobertoTellezIbarra it was mistake :)

Comment: @BahaBaghdadi what do mean by `how can I calculate the value of (dd + mm + yyyy) `

Comment: well dd, mm and yyyy are int so I want to make the addition. for exemple : if dd = 11, mm = 22, yyyy= 3333 ==> i want to display : dd+mm+yyyy = 3366.

Answer (score 4):

You must retrieve values of `EditText` after it is filled. You can't ensure this inside `onCreate` as you are trying to retrieve values as soon as view is up and user doesn't get chance to enter those values in `EditText`.

Retrieve values of `EditText` inside `onClick`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String dds = ddtext.getText().toString();
    final int dd = Integer.parseInt(dds);                          //error

    String mms = mmtext.getText().toString();
    final int mm = Integer.parseInt(mms);                           //error

    String yyyys = yyyytext.getText().toString();
    final int yyyy = Integer.parseInt(yyyys); 

    output.setText("you wrote:" + (dd + mm + yyyy));
}
```